# Trying to figure out Ruby on Rails remote: true callbacks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

So I've been googling on how to set them up, I ended up with this code in the end.

```
<script>

$('#reportform')
    .bind("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('#reportalert').text('Done.');
    });
    .bind("ajax:error", function(xhr, status, error) {

        $('#reportalert').text('Failed.');

    });

</script>


<h2>Review Driver</h2>
<p>Fill out your review of the driver</p>   

<div class="hero-unit form-signin" id="reportformdiv">

    <%= form_for(@report, html: { id: "reportform" }, remote: true, update: 
    { success: "response", failure: "error"} ) do |t| %>
<p id="reportalert"></p>
    <%= t.text_field  :plant_site,    placeholder: "Plant Site" %>

    <%= t.text_field  :route_number,  placeholder: "Route Number" %>

    <%= t.text_field  :driver_name,   placeholder: "Driver name if available" %>

    <%= t.date_select :date_recorded, html: { class: "input-block-level" } %>

    <%= t.text_field  :action,        placeholder: "Action taken" %>

    <%= t.text_area   :report_body,   placeholder: "What you witnessed",
                                     style: "height: 300px;",
                                     class: "input-block-level" %>

    <%= t.submit     "File Report",  class: "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>

    <% end %>

</div>
```

But it is not working and I have no idea why, I'm sure I've done something wrong, I'm new to RoR and I love the fact that I can declare this remote: true in the form its self, once I figure out how to set the callbacks I'll be good to go :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your brower's log console tells you when you try to submit the form? (Accessible in Google Chrome by pressing F12)

Comment: @MrYoshiji nothing, the console reports. Nothing.

Comment: You want to work it this way?? I have solution using `jquery` not with using `:remote => true`. I am pretty sure it will work like charm. Is it ok ??

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to [Rails' wiki](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax), the code bellow should work:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reportform').on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr){
      $('#reportalert').text('Done.');
    }).on('ajax:error',function(e, xhr, status, error){
      $('#reportalert').text('Failed.');
    });
  });
</script>
```

A similar code worked for me in Rails 3.2.14 and jquery-rails 3.0.4

Hope it helps.

Comment: If anyone wants to know how to get a hold of the actual error messages, the response body is evidently contained in `e.detail`.

Comment: If the target for the form is '_blank' and the response from the server is downloading a PDF, should these events still fire? My initial testing indicates no response. Anyway to catch this scenario when the file is returned to the client from the server? Or a way to fire call javascript function in client from server while also returning the pdf without a double-render issue?

Comment: If you add an `ajax:success` handler and it doesn't appear to work, the issue could be that the Ajax request fails – this can happen even if it's a 200 response, e.g. if you don't return JSON. You can verify by adding an `ajax:error` handler as in the example above.

Answer (score 9):

Since Rails 5.1, response, status, and xhr must be extracted through event.detail see: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers

This is one possible solution:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '#reportform', event => {
  const [response, status, xhr] = event.detail;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up !
This is now stable: [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html]

Answer (score 4):

**Turbolinks compatible**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('ajax:success', 'a[data-remote].watching', function(e, data, status, xhr){

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Put your javascript code on `document ready`:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#reportform')
    .bind("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('#reportalert').text('Done.');
    });
    .bind("ajax:error", function(xhr, status, error) {

        $('#reportalert').text('Failed.');

    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use jQuery. Could do:

```js
document.querySelector('#reportform')
    .addEventListener("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr) {
        document.querySelector('#reportform').text('Done.');
    });
    .addEventListener("ajax:error", function(xhr, status, error) {
        document.querySelector('#reportform').text('Failed.');
    });
```