# Detect server down when submit remote: true in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Can I detect when client couldn't send request to server ? (server down or broken internet link or something ...)

Exp. when I submit form or click link with `remote: true`, if request couldn't come to server, I could show a message to user.

```
<%= form_for @item, remote: true do %>
    ....
<% end %>

 or

<%= link_to @item, remote: true %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write AJAX callbacks for `remote: true` requests like below.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#item').on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
      //Success action
    }).on('ajax:error',function(e, xhr, status, error){
      //Failure action
    });
  });
</script>
```

You can write whatever you want in the error block.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395105/trying-to-figure-out-ruby-on-rails-remote-true-callbacks)