# how to submit form data without page reload in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

`project_director` table has an attribute status,that has one_to_one association with `project`. 
i am rendering projects with project_director form, on form submission every time my page reloads. i tried ajax from online resources but still my page reloads. here is what  i tried.

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for ProjectDirector.new do |f| %>
<td>
   <table class="approval-table">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <ul>
               <div>
                  <div class="wrapper-class">
                     <%= f.radio_button :status, true  %>
                     <%= f.label :approve %>
                     <br>
                     <%= f.radio_button :status, false  %>
                     <%= f.label :reject %>
                  </div>
                  <%=f.hidden_field :project_site_id, value: project_site.id%>
               </div>
            </ul>
         </td>
         <td>
            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
            <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button primary small' %>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <script>
      $(function(){
          $("#new_project_director").on("submit", function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
      
              var formData = {
                  'status': $('input[name=project_director[status]]').val() //for get status
              };
              console.log(formData);
      
              $.ajax({
                  url: "/project_directors",
                  type: "post",
                  data: formData,
                  success: function(d) {
                      alert(d);
                  }
              });
          });
      })
      
   </script>
  </td>
```

project_directors_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @project_director =  ProjectDirector.new(remark_params)
      if @project_director.save
        redirect_to directors_index_path(anchor: 'panel2')
    end
  end
```

```
def remark_params
  params.require(:project_director).permit(:status, :projec_id, :user_id)
end
```

Comment: Have you looked into [Rails remote form handling](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)?  That might help.  You can set `remote=true` in your `form_for` (i think).  It is curious because even without that, your code looks mostly right.  I wonder about the redirect.  If the `create` endpoint is truly ready for ajax, you could just return `head :ok` instead of the redirect.  I wonder if the redirect is taking over?  Are you seeing the console.log triggering when you submit?

Comment: @mrrogers added ``` remote: true```, still after one submission next submission is not working untill i reload page.

Comment: console after one submission gives this error ```Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=project_director[status]```

Comment: Well - that's good data.  The first hit correctly does *not* update the page, right?  then the second one fails.  I think with `remote=true` you probably don't need your on submit handler.   Let me see if i can mock up an answer that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails gives you a lot of help here.  I was able to get this working without a lot of extra javascript and without digging into the actual form fields because Rails already knows how that stuff is shaped and how
it should work together.

Note:  I have a model called `Thing` which has an `accepted` boolean attribute.  This should correspond to your `ProjectDirector` (roughly).

in the form

```
<%= form_for(thing, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :accepted %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button primary small' %>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller

```
# things_controller.rb
  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)


    if @thing.save
      if request.xhr?
        render json: { success: true }
      else
        redirect_to @thing, notice: "Thing was successfully created."
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

If I create a new `Thing` the page does not refresh and it honors my boolean value.

You'll notice that there is no real additional javascript.  Rails UJS handles this for me just by adding `remote: true` to the form.

This does not handle the possible redirect that you're trying to do which is to load up a new tab on the site.  To trigger actions *after* a successful submit,
you can add listeners for success and failure for that with something like

```
 $('#my-form-id').on('ajax:success', function(event){
    const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail
    alert(xhr.responseText)
    // or 
    alert(data.success)
 }).on('ajax:error',function(event){
    alert("Something went wrong")
 });
```

Check out [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395105/trying-to-figure-out-ruby-on-rails-remote-true-callbacks) or
read Ruby on Rails guides [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: data is correctly passing now without page reload, but no sucess or error message is shown to user

Comment: at this point the rails `flash` doesn't really work for you.  it's counting on page reloads.  So you'll have to handle that in the `ajax:success` listener.  You can certainly update the response from the controller to hand back the success message like `render json: { success: "Way to go"}` then in the front end you'll need to put it on the page with javascript.

Comment: first time i am adding ajax so could you tell me how can i put on the page with javascript?

Comment: I updated the solution and what your `ajax:success` event listenters might look like.

Comment: i have added turbo links but still alert response i only see on first submission not 2,3.. submission without page reload

Comment: If you're using turbolinks, you need to change your document.onReady setup.  Check out https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks.  The short story is that `$(function() { ... run when dom is ready ... })` which is what you have is insufficient.  You'll need to an extra copy of that that is like `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { ... run when dom is ready ... {))`.  But I'd read the docs in that link or this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110789/rails-5-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links.